# Getting value from xml using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Having following xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><id ext="1" root="2" />
```

How can I get value of extension and root using xslt transform?

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="id/@ext" /> and the same you can do for root

Comment: So whole xslt file should look like this one?: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:value-of select="id/@ext" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
Unfortunately it does not work :/ I am using this editor http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_ex2

Comment: your attribute is ext while you are using extension in your file

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="id/@extension" />  should be  <xsl:value-of select="id/@ext /> ..the xml you mentioned has no attribute extension

Comment: corrected, but still does not work.

Comment: you need to give the parent context

Comment: see my answer below.it works on the editor you mentioned

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work . Associate the template with the root of the XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:random="http://www.microsoft.com/msxsl">
         <xsl:template match="/">
             <xsl:value-of select="id/@ext" />
             <xsl:value-of select="id/@root" />
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```